# When was the Wolkenritter summoned?

Tags: nanoha

In *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha A's*, at the very beginning of the first episode, it showed the Book of Darkness activating. Later in the series, it showed this again, but continuing on showing that the Wolkenritter were summoned at this time, and they lived like a regular family with Hayate.

When they learn that the Book of Darkness was draining Hayate, the Wolkenritter began to attack the Time Space Administration in order to fill all the pages, thinking that by doing so they could save Hayate.

The *Book of Darkness Incident*, which would be the reference to the clashes between the Wolkenritter and the TSAB (particularity with Nanoha and Fate involved) is documented to have occurred in 0065 of the Mid-Childan Calendar, the same year that the Jewel Seed Incident occurred (first season of *Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha*).

I am wondering, when were the Wolkenritter actually summoned to Hayate's side? Was it before, during, or after the Jewel Seed Incident?

Answer (score 1):

Nanoha A's takes place six months after the original series, on December of the same year. The Book of Darkness was activated on midnight 3/4 July, as seen in the first episode of A's.

The conclusion is that the activation of the Book of Darkness and appearance of the Wolkenritter occurred just after the conclusion of the Jewel Seed incident.